# RequireJs/AngularJS how services access the controller

Tags: angularjs, requirejs

RequireJS and AngularJS.

If i try to access the controller inside a service I get the error.

Argument 'onCloseAlert' is not a function, got undefined.

This service is call by other controller (other file).

The code for the service.

```
(function( define ) {
"use strict";
define([],
    function() {
        var AlertService = function( $modal, $log ) {
            var onShowAlert = function( alertTitle, alertMessage ) {
                var modalInstance = $modal.open({
                    templateUrl : 'app/moduloUtils/viewmodel/alert.html',
                    controller  : 'onCloseAlert'
                });
                return {
                    alertTitle   : alertTitle,
                    alertMessage : alertMessage
                };
            };
            var onCloseAlert = function( $modalInstance ) {
                $modalInstance.close();
                return true;
            };
            return {
                showAlert  : onShowAlert,
                closeAlert : onCloseAlert
            };
        };
        return [ "$modal", "$log", AlertService ];
    }
);
}( define ));
```

Thank You

Comment: i suppose you are using some angular ui componets, can give more information on this? and i think `onCloseAlert` should be a real angular controller but not just a function

Comment: Yes I use ui.bootstrap ($modal)

Answer (score 0):

For the controller to be specified as string, it has to be registered with `angular.controller('onCloseAlert', ...)`, or it has to be a *global* function (and be enabled using `$controllerProvider.allowGlobals()`). In your case, `onCloseAlert` is a name defined in the scope, so it is enough to just reference that name as:

```
            var modalInstance = $modal.open({
                templateUrl : 'app/moduloUtils/viewmodel/alert.html',
                controller  : onCloseAlert // no quotes, just reference the local
            });
```

And I would suggest using the full blown "annotations" for the controller:

```
        var onCloseAlert = ['$modalInstance', function( $modalInstance ) {
            $modalInstance.close();
            return true;
        }];
```

Comment: I made like this but the alert.html not close when click on the button ng-click='closeAlert'. maybe have to use like controller not service. i'm lost

Answer (score 0):

If I call like a service the modal show ok but HTML not call the closeAlert.

```
<div>
 <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary pull-right m-t-n-xs" ng-click="closeAlert();"><strong>Fechar</strong></button>
</div>
```

If I change and use controllers not work too. :(

**The module**

```
(function ( define, angular ) {

"use strict";

define([
        'modAute/services/Autenticacao',
        'modAute/controllers/LoginController',
        'modUtil/controllers/AlertController'
    ],
    function (LoginController, AlertController ) {

        var nomeModulo = "Autenticacao";

        angular
            .module( nomeModulo, [] )
            .service( "autenticacao", Autenticacao )
            .controller( "LoginController", LoginController )
            .controller( "AlertController", AlertController );

        return nomeModulo;
    });

}( define, angular ));
```

The LoginController

```
(function( define ) {
"use strict";
define([
        'modUtil/controllers/AlertController'
    ],
    function ( AlertController ) {
        var LoginController = function( autenticacao, $scope, $q, $log, $location ) {

                ...

                var onForgot = function() {

                        return autenticacao

                            .forgot($scope.email)

                            .then(function onResult_forgot( response ) {

                                AlertController.showAlert('Atenção', '..');

                                return true;
                            }

                };

                $scope.forgotPas    = onForgot;
        };

        return ["autenticacao", "$scope", "$q", "$log", "$location", LoginController ];

    }
);
}( define ));
```

The AlertController

```
(function( define ) {

"use strict";

define([],

    function() {

        var AlertController = function( $scope, $modal, $log ) {

            var onShowAlert = function( alertTitle, alertMessage ) {

                $scope.alertTitle   = alertTitle;
                $scope.alertMessage = alertMessage;

                var modalInstance = $modal.open({

                    templateUrl : 'app/moduloUtils/viewmodel/alert.html',
                    controller  : 'onCloseAlert'

                });

            };

            var onCloseAlert = [ '$modalInstance', function( $modalInstance ) {

                $modalInstance.close();

                return true;
            }];

            $scope.showAlert  = onShowAlert;
            $scope.closeAlert = onCloseAlert;
        };
        return [ "$scope", "$modal", "$log", AlertController ];
    }
);

}( define ));
```

Error the line 157 on LoginController is  **AlertController.showAlert('Atenção', '..');**

TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at onResult_forgot (http://lecoleco.desenv/sysAdmin/app/moduloAutenticacao/controllers/LoginController.js:157:53)